# fastest method for determining needle in haystack

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I have my request URI:

```
string '/admin' (length=16)
```

And I have an array of locale codes:

```
array (size=2)
 'US' => string 'en_US' (length=5)
 'FR' => string 'fr_FR' (length=5)
```

What I am looking for is to determine that the request URI does not have a locale code from the array provided.

If it doesn't, I need to inject a locale code before the word `admin` so it will look as follows: `/en_US/admin`

What is the fastest method for handling this task? Id need a fast search method against a large set of locales and then some way to inject the locale at the beginning of the request URI

Comment: a forloop of the locale codes that does a stristr against the requestURI

Comment: explode, in_array ..

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$uri_splitup = explode('/', $request_uri)
if (in_array($uri_splitup[0], $locales)) {
    // localised URI
} else {
    // not-localised URI
}
```

With [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), you split the request URI up with the slashes. It returns an array. After that, with [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), you check if the first part of the URI exists in the values of the array with the locales.

The time complexity of explode() can be considered constant as your URI will probably always have more or less the same length. Also, this part of the code won't take so much time on normal lengths. The time complexity of in_array() is *O(n)* with *n* the number of elements in your array. You can't get a faster search algorithm on an unsorted array.